# Azure notification hub, notification log

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Is there a log of messages sent to devices and when in the Azure Notification Hub?

All I can find is the Activity Log which only seems to show service management type activities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Free and Basic tiers you get the overall metrics/counters chronologically via the portal:
[image]

In Standard you can get [Per Message Telemetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608135.aspx) which gives you detailed information about every sent notification.

Let me know if I didn't understand your question correctly.

Comment: Yes you understand it correctly. I'm just in dev mode at the moment, so using the free/basic. Where in the portal do i see overall metrics/counters chronologically?

Comment: Updated the answer with a screenshot of how to get the monitoring in the portal. As of Feb 2017 go to the hub blade (`Overview`) and it would be there by default.